# Insert records in two tables in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi guys I started MVC ASP.NET in last week and I have healthy progress in it. Now I have some idea about 
Creating control, attaching views, database (saving, fetching records), classes in models etc.

Till now I can open page with one object (strongly) attached

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) 
{
    Book book = db.BOOKS.Find(id);
    return View(book);
}
```

and send it back to controller with added information in text field and save.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Book book) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(book);
}
```

Till now everything is good. Here comes the real question.

Lets say I have one more table BookReview which contains.

```
Int ID (identity)
Int BookID 
Varchar comments
```

**Now what I want is when user open a page and wants to add some comments against book. So this comments should go to the BookReview table with book id and Book related data should go to Book table**. So my imaginary picture is like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Book book, BookReview review) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Entry(review).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(book);
}
```

And next time when user click on same book so she/he could see book info as well as added comments.

I have no idea how to insert records in two tables using MVC

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed something like that ?

```
db.Books.AddObject(book);
db.Reviews.AddObject(review);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I think that your problem is more related to the Entity Framework, and to "Linq to entities". This might help you for your next bing researchs.

btw, you also need to bind the reviews to the view.

I think the best way to do it would be to create a ViewModel.

You might want to call it BookAndReviewViewModel, and use it like that :

```
public class BookAndReviewViewModel {
   public Book book {get; set;}
   public BookReview bookReview {get; set;}
}
```

And then using it that way in your controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(BookAndReviewViewModel bookAndReview) 
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid) 
     {
         db.Books.AddObject(bookAndReview.book);
         db.Reviews.AddObject(bookAndReview.bookReview);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return View(bookAndReview);
}
```